# Warum fängt dieser Satz mit "den" an?

Tags: accusative

Ohne "den" wäre er auch korrekt, oder? Spielt dieses eine besondere Rolle?

> WIE KÖNNEN WIR DIE LÜCKE SCHLIESSEN?
> Den einen Schalter, den man umlegen kann, gibt es nicht. Deswegen setzen wir an vielen Stellen gleichzeitig an.

[image: WIE KÖNNEN WIR DIE LÜCKE SCHLIESSEN? Den einen Schalter, den man umlegen kann, gibt es nicht. Deswegen setzen wir an vielen Stellen gleichzeitig an.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Einen Schalter …

Das ist einfach irgendein Schalter.

> Den Schalter …

Das ist ein bestimmter Schalter, über den vorher schon gesprochen wurde.

> Den einen Schalter …

Das ist ein bestimmter Schalter, über den vorher **nicht** gesprochen wurde.

Diese letzte Konstruktion wird oft eingesetzt, um auszudrücken, dass es eine Reihe von Möglichkeiten gibt, von denen eine die richtige ist. Man weiß aber nicht, welche.

Comment: "Das ist ein bestimmter Schalter, über den vorher nicht gesprochen wurde." Unsinn! Es gibt viele Pseudowissenschaftler, die an einer allumfassenden Grammatik arbeiten, aber die eine Grammatik gibt es bisher nicht.

Comment: Keine Ahnung. Ich kenn ja keine Pseudowissenschaftler. Persönlich, mein ich.

Answer (score 5):

> Den einen Schalter, den man umlegen kann, gibt es nicht.

Das bedeutet, dass eine einzelne Maßnahme ("der eine Schalter") nicht ausreicht, um die beklagte Lücke zu schließen. Es bedarf mehrerer Maßnahmen, um das Problem zu lösen. Das wird im Folgesatz

> Deswegen setzen wir an vielen Stellen gleichzeitig an.

klargemacht.

Sprachlich korrekt ist auch der Satz

> Einen Schalter, den man umlegen kann, gibt es nicht.

Ich erkenne aber eine etwas andere Bedeutung - er klingt pessimistischer als der Satz oben. "Einen Schalter gibt es nicht" suggeriert, dass es gar keine Maßnahme gibt, die das Problem löst.

Als englische Entsprechung für "den einen Schalter" könnte man "silver bullett" verwenden:

> There is no silver bullet to solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Das ist Idiomatisch. Die grammatische Einordnung scheint mir schwierig zu sein, weil bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel vermischt werden.

Tatsächlich ist "einen" in solchen Wendungen als Adverb zu verstehen

> Den *einen* Schalter gibt es nicht

> Die Gleichung hat *keine* eindeutige Lösung

In dieser Hinsicht wäre es falsch, das Adverb zu einem unbestimmten Artikel umzuformen.

Der vorangestellte bestimmte Artikel scheint demzufolge einfach die Nominalphrase einzuleiten. Offensichtlich wird da nie ein unbestimmter Artikel verwendet

> ? *Einen einen Schalter gibt es nicht.*

Obwohl die Syntax plausibel ist

> *Einen magischen Schalter gibt es nicht.*

Heute wäre es auch ansatzweise ungrammatisch, den Artikel auszulassen.

> * [...] *magischen* Schalter gibt es nicht.

Außer im Plural

> *Magische* Schalter gibt es nicht.

Früher—viel früher—wäre das allerdings gegangen. Für die hiesige Betrachtung ist das zwar relativ egal. Der Ursprung der Artikel ist bei synchronischer Betrachtung soweit grammatikalisiert worden, dass es in der Sache keinen Unterschied macht. Insoweit muss die Formel, *Den einen gibt es nicht*, als idiomatisch gelten, weil die Bedeutung sich erst aus der Betonung ergibt (Akzentsitz auf *einen* entsprechend der Verwendung als Adverb; allerdings verschiebt sich der Akzent weiter auf den Wortanfang, *deneinen*).

Andersherum wird kein Schuh daraus:

> ? *Einen Schalter, den man umlegen kann, gibt es nicht.*

Die Aussage wäre irgendwie Paradox, weil jeder Schalter per definition umgelegt werden kann. Für Metaphern besteht natürlich Spielraum, doch ergibt sich dieser nicht ohne Kontext. Der Kontext folgt in der gesuchten Parole erst später im Text. Daher ist diese Alternative nicht als Einleitung geeignet.

Prinzipiel ist der Ansatz aber nicht falsch, da so ein bestimmter Artikel in vergleichbaren Aussagesätzen häufig nicht gegeben ist. Das folgende Beispiel soll gleichfalls als Tenor meiner Antwort herhalten:

> Eine Lösung, die alle befriedigen kann, gibt es nicht.