# Determiner before Genitivatrribut/Possessivpronomen

Tags: genitive, possessive-pronoun, determiners

Recently I found an [example sentence in DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zugutetun#d-1-2) under the entry "zugutetun":

> Goethe war bis an sein Lebensende stolz auf **dieses sein Jugendwerk**, auf das er sich, neben dem Faust, am meisten zugute tat.

I am baffled by the syntactic nature of "sein" between "dieses" and "Jugendwerk". Should it be interpreted as the obsolete form of genitive pronoun or rather an possessive adjective? As far as I am concerned, modern standard German does not seem to allow a determiner to directly precede either a Genitivattribut or a Possessivpronomen. Since when has this rule been in effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The construction has an exact parallel in English, though it is rarer and more old-fashioned in English than in German. There’s a well-known prayer that begins, “O God, the Father of humankind, who has blessed me with **these my children** and committed them to my charge to raise them…”. The more common construction in current English would have ‘these children of mine’ instead of ‘these my children’, but both are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination is allowed even in today's standard German.

> **Sein** Jugendwerk …

That's simply **his** early works.

> **Dieses** Jugendwerk …

That's **particular** early works which we talked about earlier.

> **Dieses sein** Jugendwerk …

That's **his particular** early works which we talked about earlier.

It's a similar situation as in [this recent question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/73320/warum-f%C3%A4ngt-dieser-satz-mit-den-an) albeit not as common. I recommend not to use it yourself as the situations in which it may be used are somewhat tricky to make out. I had to ponder a lot whether I do this in a particular phrasing or not. It creates a lot of emphasis.

Comment: Hierbei ist "sein" also ein Possessivpronomen. Sind Phrasen wie "der sein" oder "ein sein" ebenfalls gebräuchlich?

Comment: Nein, die sind gänzlich unüblich.

Answer (score -3):

Dabei scheint es sich um eine abgeschliffene Art Höflichkeitsformel in gehobener Sprache zu handeln.

DWDS sagt zum Possessivpronomen *sein*

> [**sein**<sup>2</sup> … germ. **sīna-*] gehen auf ein mit dem Suffix ie. *-no-* gebildetes Adjektiv zum Lokativ ie. **sei* zurück, der seinerseits zum Pronominalstamm ie. **se-* (s. *sich*) gehört.

> […] Als Ausgangsbedeutung für das Possessivpronomen ist anzusetzen ‘bei ihm befindlich’, dann ‘zu ihm gehörig’.

> „sein“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al.

Vergleichsmöglichkeiten gibt Pfeifer dafür kaum.

Bekannt ist lateinisch *per se* ohne Lokativ. Dabei wird heute üblicher Weise auf ie. **swe-* abgestellt, vgl. französisch *son* "sein", lateinisch *suus*, lokativ *suī*. Deswegen ist die Frage ernst zu nehmen und die Wendung kritisch zu betrachten.

Entsprechend meiner Antwort in der anderen Frage ([Warum fängt dieser Satz mit "den" an?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73333/35977)) dürfte es sich um ein Adverb handeln.

> auf dieses *sein* Werk

> auf dieses *von ihm allein bearbeitete* Werk

1. Denkbar ist dabei Überschneidung mit dem Verbum *sein* im Sinne *Leben*, vgl. *Lebenswerk*, i.S.v. *sich etwas zu eigen machen*. Denn auf der Bedeutungsebene heißt es ungefähr, die Leistung kann ihm keiner mehr nehmen, das ist ihm hoch anzurechnen, wie der weitere Kontext anzudeuten scheint: "Goethe war bis an sein Lebensende stolz […]", "das er sich, neben dem Faust, am meisten zugute tat." Wichtig für diesen Vergleich ist vorallem "lass das sein" (leave it allone).

   Vergleichsweise lässt sich konstatieren, dass *-lik in der Theorie ebenfalls Adverbien bzw. Adjektive zu bilden scheint und zwar als Suffix auf (pro)nominaler Basis (s. *-lich*, vgl. niederländisch *lichaam* "Körper").

   Wie oben bereits angedeutet ist, weil neben *eins*, *allein* usw. (siehe die andere Frage) mit Hettitisch *šia-* und Tocharisch A *sas, säṃ*, B *ṣe* eine weitere indoeuropäische Wurzel gehandelt wird, vermutlich *sem-, sowie Suffigierung unten noch mal angefasst wird, auch die Nominalendung *-s im Blick zu behalten.
2. Jedoch fällt auf, dass *-no- mit auslautendem *-e* niederschlägt und dem Sprachgefühl nach zumindest in den adverbialen Partizipien (*das von ihm bearbeitete*) richtig wäre, bspw. *er besteht auf das Seine*, *seinen Anteil*. Dementsprechend ist Nasalisierung des Lokativs ohne **-no-* bedenklich, quasi *sei<sup>n</sup>*, weil *-no- in nominativ *-nos (vgl. *seins, eins*, en.wiktionary), mit Lokativ konkuriert haben muss. Jenes *-s* greift offenbar analogisch in den Genitiv ein, also *seines*, vgl. dementsprechend lat. gen. *sui*.
3. Ferner stehen Höflichkeitsformeln zum Vergleich an, bspw. *seine Majestät*, engl. *her* majesty.

   Dabei ist durchaus bemerkenswert, dass die älteren Pronomina mit *s*, z.B. althochdeutsch *so*, zwar auf eine anderes Wurzelparadigma zurückgeführt werden, *só ~ *tó, und gerade nicht gebeugt werden. Genau dazu zählt höfliches *Sie* und insbesondere *dieses* und zwar scheinbar redundant (s. DWDS: *der, dieser, Sie*)

> Zusammensetzung, die ursprünglich aus den flektierten Stammformen des unter *der, die, das* (s. d.) behandelten Demonstrativums und einer indeklinablen mit *s-* anlautenden deiktischen Partikel (älter anord. *-si*, sonst *-s* oder *-se*) besteht. Diese frühe Bildungsweise, nach der das Pronomen im Wortinnern flektiert wird, ist in einigen Formen noch erhalten […]

> „diese“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al.,

> Daneben [neben dem "Pronominalstamm ie. **ei-, *i-* (vgl. *er, es*)] steht ein mit *s-* anlautender Stamm, der in got. *si* und ahd. *sī̌* (Nominativ Sing. Fem.) wie auch in einigen Formen des Demonstrativums (s. *der, die, das*, dort auch Weiteres zur Verwandtschaft) bzw. als zweiter Bestandteil des verstärkten Demonstrativums (s. *dieser, diese, dieses*) vertreten ist.

> „Sie“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al.,

> […] zu einem Pronominalstamm ie. **te-, *to-*, der auch in allen obliquen Kasus auftritt.

> In den germ. Sprachen werden die s-Formen schon früh aufgegeben und (im Ahd. vor der Überlieferung) durch analoge Bildungen den übrigen Kasus angeglichen.

> „der“, in: Wolfgang Pfeifer et al., Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993), digitalisierte und von Wolfgang Pfeifer überarbeitete Version im Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache, https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/der, abgerufen am 25.03.2023.

Ferner wird engl. *Sir* von *senior, senex* "alt" abgeleitet, was wohl sein mag, im germanischen Zweig jedoch bloß ddurch gotisch  vertreten wird. Auch *Senat* deutet auf ehrlich Aufgaben hin, vgl. *ex senatus*, ferner *sonus* (*swen-, mit deutsch *Schwan*, bzw. *Schwanz, schwatzen* usw.). Wie dem auch sei, Alter schützt vor Torheit nicht.

4. Lateinisch *sine* ist bemerkenswert, weil deutsch *so* in wenigen Wendungen Separiertheit ausdrückt. *Das kann man so nicht ohne weiteres sagen*. Zu lateinisch *sine* "without, by itself" (ohne) werden verschieden Hypothesen vertreten (en.wiktionary). Anders als die bereits genannten Wurzeln wird außerdem **senH-* angedeutet, das mit tocharisch B *snai* "separate", irisch *sain* usw. zu *sonder-* gehören würde. Die Ähnlichkeit mit *ander-* (noch mittelhochdeutsch "2") ist wiederum entbehrlich.
5. Wichtiger noch ist die mögliche Herleitung von *eigen*, engl. *own* aus dem gleichen Stamm wie *eins*, die in anbetracht der hettitischen Belegsituation auch noch nicht so alt sein kann, vgl. Sanskrit ईश (īśá) "owing, possession", "lord, master, ruler", Tocharisch B *aik-* "to know", *iśaumye* "wise, wise person" (en.wiktionary) um den Verdacht des Honorificum zu bestätigen. Ich bin aber auch verdammt gut.

Weder obsolete Formen von Genitiv oder possesivem Adjektiv führen ans Ziel. Es handelt sich offenbar um eine verknöcherte Lokativwendung ganz im Sinne von der geläufigen englischen Wendung *this'ere*. Übrigens ist auch *this my* usw. belegt:

> my father and mother strengthened me in this my first impression [1831, Nat Turner, The Confessions of Nat Turner]

Dieser Vergleichswert dürfte also schon beträchtliches Alter haben. Wegen der vorangegangenen Betrachtung hinsichich *sem- ist aber davon auszugehen, dass die die reflexive Form von *swe- in adverbialer Wendung Vorrang hat. Wirich *eindeutig* ist das aber nicht.

---

Wolfgang Pfeifer et al.:
Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen (1993), digitalisierte und von Wolfgang Pfeifer überarbeitete Version im Digitalen Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache,

- https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/der
- https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/dieser
- https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/sein
- https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/Sie

Comment: Ihre umfassende Antwort verdient meinen Beifall. Dessen unbeschadet kann man sich schon mit einer oberflächlicheren Erklärung bescheiden.

Comment: Die Antwort geht an der Frage weitgehend vorbei, denn es geht nicht um die Etymologie von "sein", sondern um die Frage, ob es sich hier um ein Possessiv handelt. Dass es sich um ein Adverb handeln soll, ist schlicht falsch.

Comment: Wiesovist das denn falsch? Die Definition von "Adverb" ist nicht eindeutig und kann deshalb nicht der entscheidende Schwachpunkt sein. Es ist ja nichtmal eindeutig, ob es sich um 1 Wort handelt. Die Frage war, seit wann dieser Gebrauch die Regel ist. Das erfordert wohl eine diakronische Einordnung, also Etymologie. Ich zeige nur, dass *meine* Etymologie das nicht ausreichend erklären kann und das weil die Etymologie komploziert ist. Dein Kommentar scheint nahezulegen, es sei ganz im Gegenteil ja einfach. Tolle Wurst! Der Frage genügt es doch festzustellen, dass das kein reiner Genitiv ist.